# Idiom for dropping a single column in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I need to drop one column from a data.frame containing a few hundred columns.

With a `data.frame`, I'd use `subset` to do this conveniently:

```
> dat <- data.table( data.frame(x=runif(10),y=rep(letters[1:5],2),z=runif(10)),key='y' )
> subset(dat,select=c(-z))
            x y
 1: 0.1969049 a
 2: 0.7916696 a
 3: 0.9095970 b
 4: 0.3529506 b
 5: 0.4923602 c
 6: 0.5993034 c
 7: 0.1559861 d
 8: 0.9929333 d
 9: 0.3980169 e
10: 0.1921226 e
```

Obviously this still works, but it seems like not a very `data.table`-like idiom.  I could manually construct a list of the column names I wanted to keep, which seems a little more `data.table`-like:

```
> dat[,list(x,y)]
            x y
 1: 0.1969049 a
 2: 0.7916696 a
 3: 0.9095970 b
 4: 0.3529506 b
 5: 0.4923602 c
 6: 0.5993034 c
 7: 0.1559861 d
 8: 0.9929333 d
 9: 0.3980169 e
10: 0.1921226 e
```

But then I have to construct such a list, which is clunky.

Is `subset` the proper way to conveniently drop a column or two, or does it cause a performance hit?  If not, what's the better way?

**Edit**

Benchmarks:

```
> dat <- data.table( data.frame(x=runif(10^7),y=rep(letters[1:10],10^6),z=runif(10^7)),key='y' )
> microbenchmark( subset(dat,select=c(-z)), dat[,list(x,y)] )
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr       min        lq    median        uq      max
1           dat[, list(x, y)] 102.62826 167.86793 170.72847 199.89789 792.0207
2 subset(dat, select = c(-z))  33.26356  52.55311  53.53934  55.00347 180.8740
```

But really where it may matter more is for memory if `subset` copies the whole `data.table`.

Comment: One question: what's your intention to drop this column? I mean what are you going to do with the resulting data.table?

Comment: @Arun The particular case that made me ask, I'd mis-named a column when creating with `:=` and wanted to drop it.  But it comes up all the time that dumping a column or two is handy.

Comment: As @mnel explains, if you want to just remove, you can directly use the `:=` operator and if you want to perform computations without this column, then you can always use `.SDcols`. So, you can avoid `subset` / `with=FALSE` solution altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are wanting to remove the column permanently use `:= NULL`

```
dat[, z := NULL]
```

If you have your columns to drop as a character string use `()` to force evaluation as a character string, not as the character name.

```
toDrop <- c('z')

dat[, (toDrop) := NULL]
```

If you want to limit the availability of the columns in `.SD`, you can pass the `.SDcols` argument

```
dat[,lapply(.SD, somefunction) , .SDcols = setdiff(names(dat),'z')]
```

However, `data.table` inspects the `j` arguments and only gets the columns you use any way. See FAQ 1.12

> When you write X[Y,sum(foo*bar)], data.table
>   automatically inspects the j expression to see which columns it uses.

and doesn't try and load all the data for `.SD` (unless you have `.SD` within your call to `j`)

---

`subset.data.table` is processing the call and eventually evaluating `dat[, c('x','y'), with=FALSE]`

using `:= NULL` should be basically instantaneous, howveer t does permanently delete the column.

Comment: mnel said: "Use`()`to force evaluation as a character string".... I've been trying to figure out how to do that for weeks.  That little tip is worthy of its own Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
dat[, !"z"]
```

Here's a benchmark on the huge data from your edit.

```
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr       min        lq    median       uq      max neval
  subset(dat, select = c(-z))  53.37435  56.82514  61.81279 100.3458 339.1400   100
            dat[, list(x, y)] 191.46678 354.39905 412.06421 451.3933 678.3981   100
                  dat[, !"z"]  53.49184  57.31756  62.15506 112.7063 398.0107   100
```

Comment: `subset.data.table` is identical to your call because they are doing the same thing see `getAnywhere('subset.data.table')`

Comment: I prefer this syntax to `subset` because of [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset). I assumed the same argument could be extended to `data.table`

Comment: @Arun Care to explain how this works?  Why's the `with` option need to be `FALSE`, for instance?

Comment: When `with=TRUE` (default), `j` is evaluated within the scope of your data.table. That is, it "sees" the columns of your data.table as variables. To overcome this default and get the same behaviour as in a data.frame, we set `with=FALSE`. If not, `DT[, "x"]` would just give you back `"x"` as `"x"` evaluates to `"x"`. [**Faq 1.1 and 1.2**](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) may be worth a read for more information.