# R: Drop columns from data.table, by reference, without having the name

Tags: r, data.table

This is *almost* a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame). I want to drop columns from a data table, but I want to do it efficiently. I have a list of names of columns that I want to keep. All the answers to the linked question imply doing something akin to

```
data.table.new <- data.table.old[, my.list]
```

which at some crucial point will give me a new object, while the old object is still in memory. However, my `data.table.old` is huge, and hence I prefer to do this via reference, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371575/1082349)

```
set(data.table.old, j = 'a', value = NULL)
```

However, as I have a whitelist of columns, and not a blacklist, I would need to iterate through all the column names, checks whether they are in `my.list`, and then apply `set()`. Is there any cleaner/other way to doing so?

Comment: use the `setdiff` of the variable names?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Idiom for dropping a single column in a data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473304/idiom-for-dropping-a-single-column-in-a-data-table) mnel's answer there is easily extended to the drop-more-than-one-column case (with `toDrop` analogous to `dropcols` in Jan's answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you can do *by reference* ops on data.frame without making it data.table.
Below code should works if you consider to use [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data.frame.old)
dropcols <- names(data.frame.old)[!names(data.frame.old) %in% my.list]
data.frame.old[, c(dropcols) := NULL]
```

Comment: I think `setdiff` is better for construction of `dropcols`

Comment: @Frank Very likely, but I personally used to the `not in` vector subset

Comment: Why doesn't `dropcols := NULL` work? What is the `c` doing?

Comment: @Farrel it evaluates `dropcols` to the character vector. Your code wouldn’t work because it would try to remove column named "dropcols" instead of the column names which `dropcols` variables stores. It doesn't need to be `c(dropcols)`, it can be `(dropcols)` which also evaluates the variable.